# Flow corresponding to sum of commuting vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification

Let $X$ and $Y$ be commuting vector fields on a smooth manifold $M$. Assume that $X,Y$ correspond to one parameter groups $\phi_X,\phi_Y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\operatorname{Diff}(M)$, respectively. I have seen that this implies that $\phi_X$ and $\phi_Y$ commute.

A remark in a book (Procesi, p. 68), says that we also have that the vector field $X+Y$ corresponds to the one parameter group $t\mapsto\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(t)$.

I tried to prove it. However, I only "proved" it, since I did not use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ commute! What is wrong with the following proof (and how can I fix it?) ?

For every $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $p\in M$:

$\frac{d}{dt}f(\phi_{X}(t)(\phi_{Y}(t)(p)))\mid_{t=0}=
\frac{d}{dt}f(\phi_{X}(t)(\phi_{Y}(0)(p)))\mid_{t=0}+
\frac{d}{dt}f(\phi_{X}(0)(\phi_{Y}(t)(p)))\mid_{t=0}=
\frac{d}{dt}f(\phi_{X}(t)(p))\mid_{t=0}+\frac{d}{dt}f(\phi_{Y}(t)(p))\mid_{t=0}=
(X+Y)(f)(p)$

And so, we are done by definition.

Comment: Thanks to the author comment, I realized that I misinterpreted the problem.  I will try when I will have some time.

Comment: @guestDiego: Thanks a lot. If you think there's something I should clarify in the question, I'd appreciate it if you tell me what was unclear.